# Extract List of object from another List of objects

Tags: java

I have a `List<User> users`, where class`User` has one property `username`. I also have another`List<User> activeUsers`. Let `users  = activeUsers + inactiveUsers`. Now I want to extract `inactiveUsers` from `users` based on `username` property. I solved this problem using two for-loops. I think this is not efficient way. so if anyone know how it can be done efficiently please let me know.

e.g. I have activeUsers[1,3] and users[1,2,3,4] and want to build inactiveUsers[2,4].

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the User class ?

Comment: no I don't allow to modify User class.

Comment: How do you identify who is active?

Comment: @Ray Stojonic:items in `activeUsers` are active.

Comment: So you have activeUsers[1,3] and users[1,2,3,4] and you want to build inactiveUsers[2,4]?

Comment: @Ray Stojonic : Yes exactly...

Comment: @Diganta are you allowed to use other structures than lists ?

Comment: @Diganta : check my answer.. I believe that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can use the [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface's [`removeAll`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method.

```
// Create a couple ArrayList objects and populate them
// with some delicious fruits.
Collection firstList = new ArrayList() {{
    add("user1");
    add("user2");
}};

Collection secondList = new ArrayList() {{
    add("user1");
    add("user1");
    add("user3");
    add("user4");
}};

// Show the "before" lists
System.out.println("First List: " + firstList);
System.out.println("Second List: " + secondList);

// Remove all elements in firstList from secondList
secondList.removeAll(firstList);

// Show the "after" list
System.out.println("Result: " + secondList);
```

The above code will produce the following output:

```
First List: [user1, user2]
Second List: [user1, user2, user3, user4]
Result: [user3, user4]
```

Comment: This solution still runs in O(n^2), OP wanted a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the restriction of modifying the `User` class and nature of your question there is no way of doing it lesser than `o(n^2)` with two lists (i.e. two loops). Of course if you could have two lists of each type your problem is done.

But since you cannot than the logic is : (assuming your structures are lists only)

```
Iterate users list (o(n)) :
   - Search the active users list for the current user (o(n))
```

No matter how you look at it you get `o(n^2)`

If you could modify `User` to have activation property you can easily reduce the problem to `o(n)` by a single search

Comment: Nope, he could convert the List to a Set and then do the iteration, then it would only be O(n).

Comment: You did not read the answer as I said with two lists. And searching a set is not faster than searching a list. You need a hash map with a good hash function to reach o(1) searches)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But why talk about what he can't do instead of talking about what he can do?

Comment: Because he is restricted to the given input (two lists and a User class which he cannot modify) so the answer is no you cannot do it faster than what he described

Comment: Nowhere does he state that restriction.

Comment: See my answer. His input is lists but why would it be impossible to create a Set based on those lists? Given the huge performance boost I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: If he is allowed to do that than yes using a hashmap will work faster

Comment: Searching a Set is a constant operation.

Comment: A Set is an abstract description for a data structure. This depends on implementation so you cannot say that a Set is a constant operation. In java a Set is an interface implemented by various classes each with its own efficient implementation

Comment: "searching a set is not faster than searching a list", What List implementation do you use that's faster than any of the Set implementations? I can't think of anyone...

"You need a hash map with a good hash function to reach o(1) searches", I don't see how this is relevant. Implementing a good hash function is really simple with java, most times eclipse even does it automatically for you.

Comment: "A is not faster than B" does not mean necessarily "B is faster than A". Read about hash maps and hash functions. If you think I'm wrong let me live with it. These ping pong comments are not helping anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could store users in a Set based on if they're active or not, I would prefer a property on User but I guess you don't want that in this assignment of yours. Using this code your problem is solved in O(n) time. Assuming you haven't messed up equals/hashCode in User.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q15999468;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Users
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(u1,u2,u3,u4,u5);
        List<User> activeUsers = Arrays.asList(u3,u5);

        Set<User> activeUsersSet = new HashSet<User>(activeUsers);

        List<User> inactiveUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

        for(User user : users)
        {
            if(!activeUsersSet.contains(user))
            {
                inactiveUsers.add(user);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Inactive users: " + inactiveUsers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a list of `active users` so how i check equality of `username`?

Comment: I have a `List<User> inactiveUsers` how I get single `username`(Steve) for checking?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you, I thought you were looking for whether or not a specific user is inactive. If you post your (complete) current code I'll probably understand the task better.

Comment: I have a `List<User> users`[u1,u2,u3,u4,u5], I have another `List<User> activeUsers`[u3,u5]. Now I want to get `List<User> inactiveUsers`[u1,u2,u4].

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
List<User> inactiveUsers = new ArrayList<User>(users);
inactiveUsers.removeAll(activeUsers) ;
```

Comment: `removeAll` returns boolean value.

Comment: but it should, make sure User overrides equals